# '+' and '?' consecutively in a regex

Tags: java, regex, jax-rs

The Java EE REST specifaction, JAX-RS, describes the translation of path variables to regexes, like in `/customer/{id}`.

From JAX-RS 1.1 Spec, page 19:

> Replace each URI template variable with a capturing group containing the specified regular expression or ‘([ˆ/]+?)’ if no regular expression is specified.

The Java API doc of java.util.regex.Pattern says:

```
X?     X, once or not at all
X+     X, one or more times
```

So, what means `+?`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the `?` right after a `+` or a `*` means that it won't be greedy.

For example :
`(.*)f` in "testftestf", the first group will match "testftest"
`(.*?)f` in testftestf", the first group will match "test"

---

**Resources :**

- [regular-expressions.info - laziness instead of greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)

Comment: to clarify, an ungreedy expression is one in which the shortest possible match is made, vs in a greedy one, the longest possible one is made.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. But what does it mean in this case `([ˆ/]+?)`? As far as I understand everything is read up to the next `/`, would it be greedy or not.

Comment: In this case the `[ˆ/]+` part would be lazy and try to catch only one character (`+` is at least one) with [^/]*? nothing would be caught.